# Android NewsReader Demo Project Problems

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded the android demo newsreader project from [here](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NewsReader.zip) and imported it into eclipse using the Import > Existing Projects Into Workspace.
I also added the android-support-v4.jar to the build path like it says [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/newsreader/index.html)

The problem I am getting is something to do with accessing resources. here are the errors I get.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
ReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader   line 143    Java Problem
android.app.ActionBar cannot be resolved to a variable  NewsReaderActivity.java     /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 151    Java Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'. style.xml   /NewsReaderTutorial/res/values-v11  line 23 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar'.  style.xml   /NewsReaderTutorial/res/values-v11  line 33 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.  style.xml   /NewsReaderTutorial/res/values-v11  line 28 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarTabStyle'.  style.xml   /NewsReaderTutorial/res/values-v11  line 30 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarTabTextStyle'.  style.xml   /NewsReaderTutorial/res/values-v11  line 29 Android AAPT Problem
FragmentTransaction cannot be resolved to a type    CompatActionBarNavHandler.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 54 Java Problem
FragmentTransaction cannot be resolved to a type    CompatActionBarNavHandler.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 76 Java Problem
FragmentTransaction cannot be resolved to a type    CompatActionBarNavHandler.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 84 Java Problem
OnNavigationListener cannot be resolved to a type   CompatActionBarNavHandler.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 35 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  ArticleActivity.java    /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 51 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HeadlinesFragment.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 75 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  NewsReaderActivity.java /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 76 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  NewsReaderActivity.java /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 80 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  NewsReaderActivity.java /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 82 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  NewsReaderActivity.java /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 86 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  NewsReaderActivity.java /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 101    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  NewsReaderActivity.java /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 152    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  NewsReaderActivity.java /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 183    Java Problem
Tab cannot be resolved to a type    CompatActionBarNavHandler.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 54 Java Problem
Tab cannot be resolved to a type    CompatActionBarNavHandler.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 76 Java Problem
Tab cannot be resolved to a type    CompatActionBarNavHandler.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 84 Java Problem
TabListener cannot be resolved to a type    CompatActionBarNavHandler.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 35 Java Problem
The import android.app.ActionBar cannot be resolved CompatActionBarNavHandler.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 19 Java Problem
The import android.app.ActionBar cannot be resolved CompatActionBarNavHandler.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 20 Java Problem
The import android.app.ActionBar cannot be resolved CompatActionBarNavHandler.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 21 Java Problem
The import android.app.FragmentTransaction cannot be resolved   CompatActionBarNavHandler.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 22 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type NewsReaderActivity  NewsReaderActivity.java /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 137    Java Problem
The method onNavigationItemSelected(int, long) of type CompatActionBarNavHandler must override or implement a supertype method  CompatActionBarNavHandler.java  /NewsReaderTutorial/src/com/example/android/newsreader  line 65 Java Problem
```

I know it's not a lot to go on but I have been searching around and couldn't find anything as its quite a new demo.

I think it could be that the R.java file is not being generated as I can't find it in my gen directory. I have tried cleaning the project and restarting eclipse but they didnt work.

Any help would be grand.

Disco

Comment: your linked source project is working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its been a while but this fixed the problem for me.
Did you import:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
```

for some reason my project had:

```
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
```

`import android.app.ActionBar;` and it worked.

Comment: +1 This solved my problem (wrong import)! I am building against SDK Version 14 (4.0). Having set android:minSdkVersion="11" and android:targetSdkVersion="17".

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your build target to be API Level 11 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the project properties file under the Android Manifest.xml file and change the target from 8 to your target 13 or above.